# Converting AVX2 operation _mm256_permute4x64_pd to AVX instructions

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, intrinsics

I have written the following method to permute the contents of a 4x double AVX register `__m256d`:

```
template <std::size_t I0, std::size_t I1, std::size_t I2, std::size_t I3>
auto permute(const __m256d& r) const
{
    return _mm256_permute4x64_pd(r, (I3 << 6) | (I2 << 4) | (I1 << 2) | I0);
}
```

This uses the AVX2 instructions `_mm256_permute4x64_pd`. Is it possible to write a method that does the same thing using only AVX instructions?

I know one way would be to specialise the method 16 times and hand code the various combinations (which I could do without help), but just wondered if there is a reasonably optimal and clever way to do it in one method using the `I0...I3`.

Comment: Yeah, there are efficient things you can do for some template params with some metaprogramming.  If you only need in-lane shuffles, you can do it with AVX VPERMILPD.  In other cases, you maybe have to unpack to two 128b lanes.  In that case have a look at what VPSHUFPD can do.

Comment: Also note that if what you're working on has a GPL-compatible license, you should look at Agner Fog's [vectorclass library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass).  It uses template metaprogramming to implement two-input shuffles, including detecting special cases like when only blend is needed.  (Last I checked, it's still missing special cases for immediate-shuffles, though.  I never got around to implementing that proposed improvement.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes, didn't think to check if Agner Fog had done it :-) A quick search for _mm256_permute4x64_pd in his vectorf256.h yielded an example. Thanks :-)